# iterate through two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following models and lists

```
public class MCashTransactions
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int CashAccountId { get; set; }

}

public class MCashAccount
{
    public int id { get; set; }       

}

 List<MCashTransactions> CashTransactions = new List<.MCashTransactions>();
 List<MCashAccount> CashAccounts = new List<MCashAccount>();
```

I want to filter the list `List<.MCashTransactions> CashTransactions` with property `CashAccountId` and `id` of list `List<MCashAccount> CashAccounts`

All I have done so far is to iterate and check on each iteration whether it exists or not. Any better way to achieve this with linq?

```
for (int i = 0; i < CashTransactions.Count; i++)
        {
         for (int j = 0; j < CashAccounts.Count; j++)
          {
            if (CashTransactions[i].CashAccountId==CashAccounts[i].id)
              {
              //work to be done here
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: So you want to join the 2 lists together?

Comment: No, there is another list in which I want to save results but only of those which exists in list CashAccounts

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can perform a [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) on two lists.

```
var joined = from ct in CashTransactions
             join ca in CashAccounts
                 on ct.CashAccountId equals ca.id
             select new { CashTransaction = ct, CashAccount = ca };

foreach (var item in joined)
{
    //Do whatever with item.CashAccount and item.CashTransaction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from ct in CashTransactions
            select new
            {
                 cashTransaction = ct,
                 cashAccount = CashAccounts.Where(p=>p.id == ct.CashAccountId).SingleOrDefault()
            };
```

SingleOrDefault() return only one item from the list (CashAccount), if exists more results - throw exception. If not result - return 0 - for structs, null - for reference type.

```
foreach(var q in query)
{
      //you can here use q.cashTransaction and object q.cashAccount/ q.cashAccount.Id
}
```